# Generate feature xml with feature dependencies using maven plugin

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf

I am using the maven-feature-plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>features-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate-features-xml</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <bundles>src/main/resources/bundle.properties</bundles>
                        <kernelVersion>2.3.6</kernelVersion>
                        <outputFile>target/features.xml</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
```

This works pretty well but one of my generated features depends on the `pax-cdi` feature is there a way for me to get the plugin to add this for me? For example I have some dependencies defined in the `bundle.properties` file that cannot be resolved automatically, could I add a feature in this file as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the feature as a maven dependency in your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.cdi</groupId>
    <artifactId>pax-cdi-features</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0</version>
    <classifier>features</classifier>
    <type>xml</type>
</dependency>
```

This will result a feature.xml containing the pax-cdi features (providing that karaf-maven-plugin is configured with `<aggregateFeatures>true</aggregateFeatures>`).

You can also leave it to the container to pull in the pax-cdi feature. Just edit $KARAF_HOME/etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg where you can enlist your pax-cdi-features by adding the maven url to the list of featuresRepositories.

```
featuresRepositories=....
                     ....,\
                     mvn:org.ops4j.pax.cdi/pax-cdi-features/0.8.0/xml/features
```

Then add pax-cdi to the list of boot features

```
featuresBoot=.....,pax-cdi,...
```

Karaf will start the bundles of pax-cdi when it boots, so that your bundles can find those cdi packages available.

Comment: I hope you can help me a little bit with this as well. I have an instance of the karaf maven plugin that genereates a feature file for me, which is depending on cxf. When i add <aggregateFeatures>true</aggregateFeatures> to the plugin config, all of cxf's features are correctly unpacked into my features.xml file, but the <feature>cxf</feature> dependency is not added to my own feature. Isn't it supposed to list these as dependencies in my own feature, instead of just unpacking them? I should point out that i am running karaf 3.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the karaf convention is that the pax-cdi feature should be provided by the container itself, so you don't need to add those bundles to your feature descriptor.
To use pax-cdi feature in karaf enter the following in your Karaf shell

features:addurl mvn:org.ops4j.pax.cdi/pax-cdi-features/0.8.0/xml/features

Comment: They renamed features:addurl to features:repo-add in Karaf3.0